# How do I get a child TextMeshPro component from a game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object with a TextMeshPro text input component and I’m not sure how to retrieve the text from this object programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using TMPro;


string inputFieldTxt = GameObject.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
```

Comment: Thabnk you. How do I modify the text? I tried getting the textcomponent and using setText() but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify the text of the ```TMP_InputField```? For simple display you can use a ```TMP_Text``` component. In any case, setting the text can be done by doing ```GameObject.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = "some text"```.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `GetComponentInChildren`

```cs
private TextMeshProUGUI TMP_1;
private void Start()
{
    TMP_1 = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>(); // or TextMeshPro
}
```